# Retry module interfering with 429 Retry-After logic

Tags: python, python-requests-html, retry-logic, http-status-code-429, riot-games-api

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry
from csv import writer
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

def make_request():
    fixed_api_key= '(insert api-key here)' 

    owner='problematic'
    start_at= 5995826513  #last match ID to be collected in previous session
    matchnum= start_at+1 #which match ID # to start at
    howmany= 3000 #how many IDs to go through in this session
    csv_name=str(start_at)+' 부터 '+str(howmany)+'개 '+owner+'.csv'
    count=0 #internal running tracker of how many match ID's have been read
    notfound=0
    entry=0
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(total=3,connect=2,other=1, backoff_factor=0.5)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
    matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
    r= session.get(matchdata)
    print(r.headers.get('X-App-Rate-Limit-Count'))
    while matchnum<(start_at+howmany):
        if r.status_code==200:
            notfound=0
            print(str(matchnum)+' SUCCESS, entrynumber #'+ str(entry))
            info= r.json()['info']
            i0= info['gameCreation']
            i0a= pd.to_datetime(i0, unit='ms')
            i1= info['gameDuration'] 
            i2= info['gameEndTimestamp'] 
            i2a= pd.to_datetime(i2, unit='ms')
            i3= info['gameId']
            i4= info['gameMode']
            i5= info['gameStartTimestamp']
            i5a= pd.to_datetime(i5, unit='ms')
            i6= info['queueId']
            infodata= [i0a,i1,i2,i2a,i3,i4,i5,i5a,i6]
            
            with open (csv_name, 'a', newline="") as f_object:
                writer_object = writer(f_object)
                writer_object.writerow(infodata)
                f_object.close()
            
            sleep(0.2)
            matchnum= matchnum+1
            entry= entry+1
            count= count+1
            if count% 50 == 0:
                print('***************COUNT SO FAR***************: '+str(count))
            j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
            matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
            r= session.get(matchdata)
            print(r.headers.get('X-App-Rate-Limit-Count'))
            
        elif r.status_code==429:
            print('we @ location : '+ str(matchnum))
            print('429, retrying after '+str(r.headers.get('Retry-After'))+ ' sec')
            sleep(int(r.headers.get('Retry-After'))+0.1)
            j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
            matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
            r=session.get(matchdata)
            print(r.headers.get('X-App-Rate-Limit-Count'))
            
        elif r.status_code==404:
            notfound= notfound+1
            print ('404, trying '+str(matchnum+1))
            if notfound>=15: #ghost block check (long stretch of 404s)
                print ('GHOST BLOCK, skipping 250')
                matchnum=matchnum+250
                count=count+250
                notfound=0 #resetting ghost block check count
            else:
                matchnum= matchnum+1
                count= count+1
            if count% 50 == 0:
                print('***************COUNT SO FAR***************: '+str(count))    
            j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
            matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
            
            r = session.get(matchdata)
            print(r.headers.get('X-App-Rate-Limit-Count'))
            
        else:
            print (r.status_code)
            sleep(10)
            j_match_id= 'KR_'+ str(matchnum)
            matchdata = 'https://asia.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/' + j_match_id + '?api_key=' + fixed_api_key
            r=session.get(matchdata)
            print(r.headers.get('X-App-Rate-Limit-Count'))
    print ("finished")
make_request()
```

The above code results in an output like:

```
5995826514 SUCCESS, entrynumber #0
2:1,2:120
404, trying 5995826516
3:1,3:120
5995826516 SUCCESS, entrynumber #1
4:1,4:120
404, trying 5995826518
1:1,5:120
404, trying 5995826519
2:1,6:120
404, trying 5995826520
3:1,7:120
404, trying 5995826521
4:1,8:120
404, trying 5995826522
5:1,9:120
5995826522 SUCCESS, entrynumber #2
1:1,10:120
404, trying 5995826524
2:1,11:120
5995826524 SUCCESS, entrynumber #3
3:1,12:120
5995826525 SUCCESS, entrynumber #4
4:1,13:120
5995826526 SUCCESS, entrynumber #5
1:1,14:120
404, trying 5995826528
2:1,15:120
404, trying 5995826529
3:1,16:120
404, trying 5995826530
4:1,17:120
404, trying 5995826531
5:1,18:120
5995826531 SUCCESS, entrynumber #6
6:1,19:120
404, trying 5995826533
1:1,20:120
404, trying 5995826534
2:1,21:120
404, trying 5995826535
3:1,22:120
404, trying 5995826536
4:1,23:120
404, trying 5995826537
5:1,24:120
404, trying 5995826538
6:1,25:120
404, trying 5995826539
7:1,26:120
404, trying 5995826540
8:1,27:120
404, trying 5995826541
1:1,28:120
404, trying 5995826542
2:1,29:120
404, trying 5995826543
3:1,30:120
404, trying 5995826544
4:1,31:120
5995826544 SUCCESS, entrynumber #7
5:1,32:120
5995826545 SUCCESS, entrynumber #8
1:1,33:120
404, trying 5995826547
2:1,34:120
5995826547 SUCCESS, entrynumber #9
3:1,35:120
5995826548 SUCCESS, entrynumber #10
4:1,36:120
5995826549 SUCCESS, entrynumber #11
1:1,37:120
404, trying 5995826551
2:1,38:120
5995826551 SUCCESS, entrynumber #12
3:1,39:120
5995826552 SUCCESS, entrynumber #13
4:1,40:120
404, trying 5995826554
1:1,41:120
404, trying 5995826555
2:1,42:120
5995826555 SUCCESS, entrynumber #14
3:1,43:120
404, trying 5995826557
4:1,44:120
5995826557 SUCCESS, entrynumber #15
1:1,45:120
404, trying 5995826559
2:1,46:120
404, trying 5995826560
3:1,47:120
404, trying 5995826561
4:1,48:120
404, trying 5995826562
5:1,49:120
404, trying 5995826563
6:1,50:120
404, trying 5995826564
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 50
1:1,51:120
404, trying 5995826565
2:1,52:120
404, trying 5995826566
3:1,53:120
5995826566 SUCCESS, entrynumber #16
4:1,54:120
404, trying 5995826568
5:1,55:120
5995826568 SUCCESS, entrynumber #17
1:1,56:120
404, trying 5995826570
2:1,57:120
5995826570 SUCCESS, entrynumber #18
3:1,58:120
5995826571 SUCCESS, entrynumber #19
1:1,59:120
5995826572 SUCCESS, entrynumber #20
2:1,60:120
5995826573 SUCCESS, entrynumber #21
3:1,61:120
5995826574 SUCCESS, entrynumber #22
1:1,62:120
404, trying 5995826576
2:1,63:120
404, trying 5995826577
3:1,64:120
404, trying 5995826578
4:1,65:120
5995826578 SUCCESS, entrynumber #23
5:1,66:120
404, trying 5995826580
6:1,67:120
5995826580 SUCCESS, entrynumber #24
1:1,68:120
404, trying 5995826582
2:1,69:120
404, trying 5995826583
3:1,70:120
5995826583 SUCCESS, entrynumber #25
4:1,71:120
404, trying 5995826585
5:1,72:120
404, trying 5995826586
6:1,73:120
5995826586 SUCCESS, entrynumber #26
1:1,74:120
5995826587 SUCCESS, entrynumber #27
2:1,75:120
404, trying 5995826589
3:1,76:120
5995826589 SUCCESS, entrynumber #28
4:1,77:120
404, trying 5995826591
1:1,78:120
5995826591 SUCCESS, entrynumber #29
2:1,79:120
404, trying 5995826593
3:1,80:120
404, trying 5995826594
4:1,81:120
5995826594 SUCCESS, entrynumber #30
1:1,82:120
404, trying 5995826596
2:1,83:120
404, trying 5995826597
3:1,84:120
5995826597 SUCCESS, entrynumber #31
4:1,85:120
404, trying 5995826599
5:1,86:120
5995826599 SUCCESS, entrynumber #32
1:1,87:120
404, trying 5995826601
2:1,88:120
5995826601 SUCCESS, entrynumber #33
3:1,89:120
5995826602 SUCCESS, entrynumber #34
4:1,90:120
404, trying 5995826604
1:1,91:120
404, trying 5995826605
2:1,92:120
404, trying 5995826606
3:1,93:120
5995826606 SUCCESS, entrynumber #35
4:1,94:120
404, trying 5995826608
5:1,95:120
5995826608 SUCCESS, entrynumber #36
1:1,96:120
404, trying 5995826610
2:1,97:120
404, trying 5995826611
3:1,98:120
404, trying 5995826612
4:1,99:120
404, trying 5995826613
5:1,100:120
404, trying 5995826614
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 100
1:1,1:120
404, trying 5995826615
2:1,2:120
404, trying 5995826616
3:1,3:120
5995826616 SUCCESS, entrynumber #37
4:1,4:120
5995826617 SUCCESS, entrynumber #38
1:1,5:120
5995826618 SUCCESS, entrynumber #39
2:1,6:120
404, trying 5995826620
3:1,7:120
404, trying 5995826621
4:1,8:120
404, trying 5995826622
1:1,9:120
5995826622 SUCCESS, entrynumber #40
2:1,10:120
5995826623 SUCCESS, entrynumber #41
3:1,11:120
5995826624 SUCCESS, entrynumber #42
1:1,12:120
5995826625 SUCCESS, entrynumber #43
2:1,13:120
5995826626 SUCCESS, entrynumber #44
3:1,14:120
404, trying 5995826628
1:1,15:120
404, trying 5995826629
2:1,16:120
5995826629 SUCCESS, entrynumber #45
3:1,17:120
404, trying 5995826631
4:1,18:120
5995826631 SUCCESS, entrynumber #46
1:1,19:120
404, trying 5995826633
2:1,20:120
404, trying 5995826634
3:1,21:120
404, trying 5995826635
4:1,22:120
404, trying 5995826636
5:1,23:120
5995826636 SUCCESS, entrynumber #47
6:1,24:120
404, trying 5995826638
1:1,25:120
404, trying 5995826639
2:1,26:120
404, trying 5995826640
3:1,27:120
5995826640 SUCCESS, entrynumber #48
4:1,28:120
404, trying 5995826642
5:1,29:120
5995826642 SUCCESS, entrynumber #49
1:1,30:120
5995826643 SUCCESS, entrynumber #50
2:1,31:120
404, trying 5995826645
3:1,32:120
404, trying 5995826646
4:1,33:120
404, trying 5995826647
1:1,34:120
404, trying 5995826648
2:1,35:120
404, trying 5995826649
3:1,36:120
404, trying 5995826650
4:1,37:120
404, trying 5995826651
5:1,38:120
404, trying 5995826652
6:1,39:120
5995826652 SUCCESS, entrynumber #51
1:1,40:120
404, trying 5995826654
2:1,41:120
404, trying 5995826655
3:1,42:120
404, trying 5995826656
4:1,43:120
404, trying 5995826657
5:1,44:120
5995826657 SUCCESS, entrynumber #52
6:1,45:120
5995826658 SUCCESS, entrynumber #53
1:1,46:120
5995826659 SUCCESS, entrynumber #54
2:1,47:120
5995826660 SUCCESS, entrynumber #55
3:1,48:120
5995826661 SUCCESS, entrynumber #56
1:1,49:120
404, trying 5995826663
2:1,50:120
404, trying 5995826664
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 150
3:1,51:120
5995826664 SUCCESS, entrynumber #57
4:1,52:120
5995826665 SUCCESS, entrynumber #58
1:1,53:120
404, trying 5995826667
2:1,54:120
5995826667 SUCCESS, entrynumber #59
3:1,55:120
5995826668 SUCCESS, entrynumber #60
1:1,56:120
404, trying 5995826670
2:1,57:120
404, trying 5995826671
3:1,58:120
404, trying 5995826672
4:1,59:120
5995826672 SUCCESS, entrynumber #61
5:1,60:120
5995826673 SUCCESS, entrynumber #62
1:1,61:120
5995826674 SUCCESS, entrynumber #63
2:1,62:120
404, trying 5995826676
3:1,63:120
404, trying 5995826677
4:1,64:120
5995826677 SUCCESS, entrynumber #64
1:1,65:120
404, trying 5995826679
2:1,66:120
5995826679 SUCCESS, entrynumber #65
3:1,67:120
404, trying 5995826681
4:1,68:120
404, trying 5995826682
5:1,69:120
404, trying 5995826683
6:1,70:120
5995826683 SUCCESS, entrynumber #66
1:1,71:120
5995826684 SUCCESS, entrynumber #67
2:1,72:120
404, trying 5995826686
3:1,73:120
404, trying 5995826687
4:1,74:120
404, trying 5995826688
5:1,75:120
5995826688 SUCCESS, entrynumber #68
1:1,76:120
5995826689 SUCCESS, entrynumber #69
2:1,77:120
404, trying 5995826691
3:1,78:120
5995826691 SUCCESS, entrynumber #70
4:1,79:120
404, trying 5995826693
1:1,80:120
404, trying 5995826694
2:1,81:120
404, trying 5995826695
3:1,82:120
404, trying 5995826696
4:1,83:120
5995826696 SUCCESS, entrynumber #71
1:1,84:120
404, trying 5995826698
2:1,85:120
404, trying 5995826699
3:1,86:120
404, trying 5995826700
4:1,87:120
404, trying 5995826701
5:1,88:120
404, trying 5995826702
6:1,89:120
404, trying 5995826703
7:1,90:120
404, trying 5995826704
8:1,91:120
404, trying 5995826705
1:1,92:120
5995826705 SUCCESS, entrynumber #72
2:1,93:120
5995826706 SUCCESS, entrynumber #73
3:1,94:120
5995826707 SUCCESS, entrynumber #74
1:1,95:120
404, trying 5995826709
2:1,96:120
404, trying 5995826710
3:1,97:120
5995826710 SUCCESS, entrynumber #75
4:1,98:120
404, trying 5995826712
5:1,99:120
5995826712 SUCCESS, entrynumber #76
1:1,100:120
404, trying 5995826714
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 200
```

which is bad since it is not printing my logic for 429 response codes when it has hit the rate limit (100:120). After not outputting anything for an arbitrary amount of time, the code then starts printing again for 100 entries. However, changing the `total` param to `total=None` or `total=0` results in a proper output and printed logic, like:

```
1:1,1:120
5995826514 SUCCESS, entrynumber #0
2:1,2:120
404, trying 5995826516
3:1,3:120
5995826516 SUCCESS, entrynumber #1
4:1,4:120
404, trying 5995826518
1:1,5:120
404, trying 5995826519
2:1,6:120
404, trying 5995826520
3:1,7:120
404, trying 5995826521
4:1,8:120
404, trying 5995826522
5:1,9:120
5995826522 SUCCESS, entrynumber #2
6:1,10:120
404, trying 5995826524
7:1,11:120
5995826524 SUCCESS, entrynumber #3
1:1,12:120
5995826525 SUCCESS, entrynumber #4
2:1,13:120
5995826526 SUCCESS, entrynumber #5
3:1,14:120
404, trying 5995826528
4:1,15:120
404, trying 5995826529
1:1,16:120
404, trying 5995826530
2:1,17:120
404, trying 5995826531
3:1,18:120
5995826531 SUCCESS, entrynumber #6
4:1,19:120
404, trying 5995826533
5:1,20:120
404, trying 5995826534
6:1,21:120
404, trying 5995826535
1:1,22:120
404, trying 5995826536
2:1,23:120
404, trying 5995826537
3:1,24:120
404, trying 5995826538
4:1,25:120
404, trying 5995826539
5:1,26:120
404, trying 5995826540
6:1,27:120
404, trying 5995826541
7:1,28:120
404, trying 5995826542
8:1,29:120
404, trying 5995826543
9:1,30:120
404, trying 5995826544
1:1,31:120
5995826544 SUCCESS, entrynumber #7
2:1,32:120
5995826545 SUCCESS, entrynumber #8
3:1,33:120
404, trying 5995826547
4:1,34:120
5995826547 SUCCESS, entrynumber #9
1:1,35:120
5995826548 SUCCESS, entrynumber #10
2:1,36:120
5995826549 SUCCESS, entrynumber #11
3:1,37:120
404, trying 5995826551
4:1,38:120
5995826551 SUCCESS, entrynumber #12
1:1,39:120
5995826552 SUCCESS, entrynumber #13
2:1,40:120
404, trying 5995826554
3:1,41:120
404, trying 5995826555
4:1,42:120
5995826555 SUCCESS, entrynumber #14
5:1,43:120
404, trying 5995826557
1:1,44:120
5995826557 SUCCESS, entrynumber #15
2:1,45:120
404, trying 5995826559
3:1,46:120
404, trying 5995826560
4:1,47:120
404, trying 5995826561
5:1,48:120
404, trying 5995826562
6:1,49:120
404, trying 5995826563
1:1,50:120
404, trying 5995826564
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 50
2:1,51:120
404, trying 5995826565
3:1,52:120
404, trying 5995826566
4:1,53:120
5995826566 SUCCESS, entrynumber #16
5:1,54:120
404, trying 5995826568
6:1,55:120
5995826568 SUCCESS, entrynumber #17
1:1,56:120
404, trying 5995826570
2:1,57:120
5995826570 SUCCESS, entrynumber #18
3:1,58:120
5995826571 SUCCESS, entrynumber #19
4:1,59:120
5995826572 SUCCESS, entrynumber #20
1:1,60:120
5995826573 SUCCESS, entrynumber #21
2:1,61:120
5995826574 SUCCESS, entrynumber #22
3:1,62:120
404, trying 5995826576
4:1,63:120
404, trying 5995826577
1:1,64:120
404, trying 5995826578
2:1,65:120
5995826578 SUCCESS, entrynumber #23
3:1,66:120
404, trying 5995826580
4:1,67:120
5995826580 SUCCESS, entrynumber #24
1:1,68:120
404, trying 5995826582
2:1,69:120
404, trying 5995826583
3:1,70:120
5995826583 SUCCESS, entrynumber #25
4:1,71:120
404, trying 5995826585
5:1,72:120
404, trying 5995826586
6:1,73:120
5995826586 SUCCESS, entrynumber #26
1:1,74:120
5995826587 SUCCESS, entrynumber #27
2:1,75:120
404, trying 5995826589
3:1,76:120
5995826589 SUCCESS, entrynumber #28
4:1,77:120
404, trying 5995826591
1:1,78:120
5995826591 SUCCESS, entrynumber #29
2:1,79:120
404, trying 5995826593
3:1,80:120
404, trying 5995826594
4:1,81:120
5995826594 SUCCESS, entrynumber #30
1:1,82:120
404, trying 5995826596
2:1,83:120
404, trying 5995826597
3:1,84:120
5995826597 SUCCESS, entrynumber #31
4:1,85:120
404, trying 5995826599
5:1,86:120
5995826599 SUCCESS, entrynumber #32
1:1,87:120
404, trying 5995826601
2:1,88:120
5995826601 SUCCESS, entrynumber #33
3:1,89:120
5995826602 SUCCESS, entrynumber #34
4:1,90:120
404, trying 5995826604
1:1,91:120
404, trying 5995826605
2:1,92:120
404, trying 5995826606
3:1,93:120
5995826606 SUCCESS, entrynumber #35
4:1,94:120
404, trying 5995826608
5:1,95:120
5995826608 SUCCESS, entrynumber #36
1:1,96:120
404, trying 5995826610
2:1,97:120
404, trying 5995826611
3:1,98:120
404, trying 5995826612
4:1,99:120
404, trying 5995826613
5:1,100:120
404, trying 5995826614
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 100
6:1,101:120
we @ location : 5995826614
429, retrying after 98 sec
1:1,1:120
404, trying 5995826615
2:1,2:120
404, trying 5995826616
3:1,3:120
5995826616 SUCCESS, entrynumber #37
4:1,4:120
5995826617 SUCCESS, entrynumber #38
1:1,5:120
5995826618 SUCCESS, entrynumber #39
2:1,6:120
404, trying 5995826620
3:1,7:120
404, trying 5995826621
4:1,8:120
404, trying 5995826622
5:1,9:120
5995826622 SUCCESS, entrynumber #40
1:1,10:120
5995826623 SUCCESS, entrynumber #41
2:1,11:120
5995826624 SUCCESS, entrynumber #42
3:1,12:120
5995826625 SUCCESS, entrynumber #43
1:1,13:120
5995826626 SUCCESS, entrynumber #44
2:1,14:120
404, trying 5995826628
3:1,15:120
404, trying 5995826629
4:1,16:120
5995826629 SUCCESS, entrynumber #45
1:1,17:120
404, trying 5995826631
2:1,18:120
5995826631 SUCCESS, entrynumber #46
3:1,19:120
404, trying 5995826633
4:1,20:120
404, trying 5995826634
5:1,21:120
404, trying 5995826635
6:1,22:120
404, trying 5995826636
1:1,23:120
5995826636 SUCCESS, entrynumber #47
2:1,24:120
404, trying 5995826638
3:1,25:120
404, trying 5995826639
4:1,26:120
404, trying 5995826640
5:1,27:120
5995826640 SUCCESS, entrynumber #48
1:1,28:120
404, trying 5995826642
2:1,29:120
5995826642 SUCCESS, entrynumber #49
3:1,30:120
5995826643 SUCCESS, entrynumber #50
1:1,31:120
404, trying 5995826645
2:1,32:120
404, trying 5995826646
3:1,33:120
404, trying 5995826647
4:1,34:120
404, trying 5995826648
5:1,35:120
404, trying 5995826649
6:1,36:120
404, trying 5995826650
7:1,37:120
404, trying 5995826651
8:1,38:120
404, trying 5995826652
1:1,39:120
5995826652 SUCCESS, entrynumber #51
2:1,40:120
404, trying 5995826654
3:1,41:120
404, trying 5995826655
4:1,42:120
404, trying 5995826656
5:1,43:120
404, trying 5995826657
6:1,44:120
5995826657 SUCCESS, entrynumber #52
1:1,45:120
5995826658 SUCCESS, entrynumber #53
2:1,46:120
5995826659 SUCCESS, entrynumber #54
3:1,47:120
5995826660 SUCCESS, entrynumber #55
1:1,48:120
5995826661 SUCCESS, entrynumber #56
2:1,49:120
404, trying 5995826663
3:1,50:120
404, trying 5995826664
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 150
4:1,51:120
5995826664 SUCCESS, entrynumber #57
1:1,52:120
5995826665 SUCCESS, entrynumber #58
2:1,53:120
404, trying 5995826667
3:1,54:120
5995826667 SUCCESS, entrynumber #59
1:1,55:120
5995826668 SUCCESS, entrynumber #60
2:1,56:120
404, trying 5995826670
3:1,57:120
404, trying 5995826671
4:1,58:120
404, trying 5995826672
5:1,59:120
5995826672 SUCCESS, entrynumber #61
1:1,60:120
5995826673 SUCCESS, entrynumber #62
2:1,61:120
5995826674 SUCCESS, entrynumber #63
1:1,62:120
404, trying 5995826676
2:1,63:120
404, trying 5995826677
3:1,64:120
5995826677 SUCCESS, entrynumber #64
4:1,65:120
404, trying 5995826679
5:1,66:120
5995826679 SUCCESS, entrynumber #65
1:1,67:120
404, trying 5995826681
2:1,68:120
404, trying 5995826682
3:1,69:120
404, trying 5995826683
4:1,70:120
5995826683 SUCCESS, entrynumber #66
5:1,71:120
5995826684 SUCCESS, entrynumber #67
1:1,72:120
404, trying 5995826686
2:1,73:120
404, trying 5995826687
3:1,74:120
404, trying 5995826688
4:1,75:120
5995826688 SUCCESS, entrynumber #68
5:1,76:120
5995826689 SUCCESS, entrynumber #69
1:1,77:120
404, trying 5995826691
2:1,78:120
5995826691 SUCCESS, entrynumber #70
3:1,79:120
404, trying 5995826693
4:1,80:120
404, trying 5995826694
5:1,81:120
404, trying 5995826695
6:1,82:120
404, trying 5995826696
1:1,83:120
5995826696 SUCCESS, entrynumber #71
2:1,84:120
404, trying 5995826698
3:1,85:120
404, trying 5995826699
4:1,86:120
404, trying 5995826700
5:1,87:120
404, trying 5995826701
1:1,88:120
404, trying 5995826702
2:1,89:120
404, trying 5995826703
3:1,90:120
404, trying 5995826704
4:1,91:120
404, trying 5995826705
5:1,92:120
5995826705 SUCCESS, entrynumber #72
6:1,93:120
5995826706 SUCCESS, entrynumber #73
1:1,94:120
5995826707 SUCCESS, entrynumber #74
2:1,95:120
404, trying 5995826709
3:1,96:120
404, trying 5995826710
4:1,97:120
5995826710 SUCCESS, entrynumber #75
1:1,98:120
404, trying 5995826712
2:1,99:120
5995826712 SUCCESS, entrynumber #76
3:1,100:120
404, trying 5995826714
***************COUNT SO FAR***************: 200
4:1,101:120
we @ location : 5995826714
429, retrying after 96 sec
```

any ideas as to what is happening would be appreciated!